# Accordion menu style in iphone using monotouch

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, custom-controls, accordion

Can we create an Accordion menu style for the iPhone using MonoTouch?

Comment: is there possible to create Accordeon menu style in iphone,if possible then how?please help me..

Comment: its like a popup,if it has 4 (buttons or) menus,clicked on any menu it shows which is having sub menus,and that clicked menu will come to down and submenus will pop over on that menu..

Comment: No such control exists natively on iOS. You'll probably need to build your own.

Comment: You could bind an existing library, like http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/accordion (there are instructions on xamarin's web site) or port it into C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MT relies on native iOS libraries for it's UI.  If a UI element exists in iOS, then you should be able to use it in MT.  As far as I know, "Accordion Menu" is not something that iOS supports.

However, this sounds like a common HTML/jQuery type control, so you may be able to achieve it by using UIWebView in your app.

Comment: can u tell me briefly i am new to this platform and onemore thing i am developing in monotouch.so please tell me briefly

Comment: a UIWebView is just an instance of Mobile Safari hosted within your app.  You can do any sort of HTML layout/control that Safari supports.  However, if you really intend to create a native app, then you should stick with Apple's native UI.